# How do I get a list containing only Azure region names?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

In the Azure Cloud Shell, I can use `az account list-locations` to get a list of all the locations supported in my subscription. How can I filter the response to only include the name property of the location and exclude all other properties?

Instead of a list of objects like this:

```
{
"displayName": "UK West",
"id": "<<removed>>",
"latitude": "53.427",
"longitude": "-3.084",
"name": "ukwest",
"subscriptionId": null
}
```

I want to get collection of names like this:

```
{
"name": "ukwest",
"name": "ukwest2",
"name": "ukwest3",
}
```

Comment: technically your JSON is invalid, it cannot contain duplicate keys. it should be `[]` - so an array containing strings or objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `-query` parameter for that:

```
az account list-locations --query '[].name'
```

its using a [jmespath](http://jmespath.org/) notation.

ps. [some](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) examples.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer didn't work for me.

I'm using the `az` CLI version 2.3.1.

This is what worked for me:

```
az account list-locations --query "sort_by([].{Location:name}, &Location)" -o table
```

Which yields this result:

```
Location
------------------
australiacentral
australiacentral2
australiaeast
australiasoutheast
brazilsouth
canadacentral
canadaeast
centralindia
centralus
eastasia
eastus
eastus2
francecentral
francesouth
germanynorth
germanywestcentral
japaneast
japanwest
koreacentral
koreasouth
northcentralus
northeurope
norwayeast
norwaywest
southafricanorth
southafricawest
southcentralus
southeastasia
southindia
switzerlandnorth
switzerlandwest
uaecentral
uaenorth
uksouth
ukwest
westcentralus
westeurope
westindia
westus
westus2
```

You can find more details on the query language here:

[Query Azure CLI command output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest)